# Atom on macOS: doesn't switch to app when opening file from shell

Tags: desktop, text-editors, window-manager, alt-tab

Using Atom (latest version) on macOS 10.15.6 Catalina. I often open files in Atom from the shell, like this:

`atom SomeDocument.txt`

When Atom is not running yet, Atom correctly appears with the specified document opened.

However if Atom was already running (which is often the case), regardless if it already had one or many or no files open, it opens my document *in the background* i.e. the Atom window does not appear.

I have to manually <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Atom (or click Atom in the Dock) to make the Atom program window come to the foreground and see my document.

Note that when I do this from the Terminal, I very briefly see 'Atom' in the top of the screen (implying it switches to Atom) but then immediately it switches back to 'Terminal' (implying it switches right back to Terminal as the active program again). When Atom was not running already, Atom remains active, like I want.

I remember this wasn't the case with previous versions, although I can't be sure if this behavior changed since an Atom update or since a macOS update, or a combination.

Is there way to make the Atom program window come to the foreground or 'switch to Atom' so to speak, whenever I open a document from the shell with it, even if Atom was already running?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this RocketNuts? I have this issue with all the apps I open in iTerm. The focus stays on iTerm.

Answer (score 0):

1. `atom SomeDocument.txt` -- Will open the file in Atom, but the window focus will remain on iTerm (or more accurately, it will switch it's focus back top iTerm like you described above.)
2. `atom . SomeDocument.txt` -- Running the command with a period will open the file and switch the window focus to Atom.